# Running Screen after switching users

Tags: file-permissions, sudo, gnu-screen, su

After switching users (with `su`) I cannot run `screen`:

```
% screen -L
Cannot open your terminal '/dev/pts/5'.
```

How can I run screen after switching users?

Comment: The terminal is owned by the original user, for security reasons others aren't allowed to access it. If you must start screen then you could open up the permissions **before** the sudo: chmod 666 $(tty); note that now other people logged into that system can read what you type, for example! Only do this if you're the only user on the system or you completely trust the others.

Comment: Does `sudo -u user screen` work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone, but this answer has better solution:

https://serverfault.com/questions/475287/gnu-screen-cannot-open-your-terminal-dev-pts-3-please-check

This peculiar problem happens bc on some high-security servers I cannot log in as root or some other user, so I have to do multiple "su - ..." sometimes. Authorizing `root` for multiuser screen session seems like better solution to me in this context.

Answer (score 2):

The TTY (terminal) you are using is owned by the initial user you log in as, and not the user you `su` to.

Because `screen` manipulates the TTY directly, it needs write access to the device node.

You should allow the user you `su` to to modify the device node somehow.

You can change the ownership to a common group:

```
# chgrp [group] $(tty)
# chmod 0660 $(tty)
```

Or (if you trust every other user on the system), you can make it world read/writeable:

```
# chmod 0666 $(tty)
```

Note that on a multi-user system, the last command can be extremely dangerous, as anyone can read and write to your TTY.